# Adding checked products to cart from wish list in magento 2.1

Tags: magento2, cart, wishlist

In wishlist I am having 5 products, I am selecting only 2 products from wishlist and clicking on Add all to cart button, it adds all five products to cart rather than adding only checked products from wish list.
Can any one help to fix this.